# NSMutableDictionary not retrieve object

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

```
EmployeesArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:100];
    Employees *Emp1 = [[Employees alloc] init];    
    Emp1.Number = 1;
    Emp1.Name = @"Jamal";
    Emp1.Age = 16;
    Emp1.Gender = @"Male";
  [EmployeesArray addObject:Emp1];
 [Dic1 setValue:Emp1 forKey:@"A"];

- (IBAction)Retrieve:(id)sender {

  Employees *objEmp2 = [Dic1 valueForKey:@"A"];
    printf(objEmp2.Name);

}
```

Why this code doesn't retrieve the name ?? and error is appeared ??

Comment: change is the same result !!!

Comment: try NSLog to print and post what error you get. ValueForKey is KVC, so i think it is OK to use it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you initialized the `Dic1` dictionary?

```
// try doing this
Dic1 = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

EmployeesArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:100];
    Employees *Emp1 = [[Employees alloc] init];    
    Emp1.Number = 1;
    Emp1.Name = @"Jamal";
    Emp1.Age = 16;
    Emp1.Gender = @"Male";
  [EmployeesArray addObject:Emp1];
 [Dic1 setObject:Emp1 forKey:@"A"];

- (IBAction)Retrieve:(id)sender {

  Employees *objEmp2 = [Dic1 objectForKey:@"A"];
    printf(objEmp2.Name);

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Three things might help.

1. use `-setObject:forKey:` instead of `-setValue:forKey`
   use `objectForKey` instead of `valueForKey` since you use custom class.
2. In general, use objective-c style `-NSLog()` instead of c style code would be easier.
3. Make sure you have imported the header file which contains the definition of Employees class instead of just using it as a forward class from your current .m file.

Comment: All conditions Done !!

Same result, Error !! Not Worked !!

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `setObject:forKey` and `objectForKey:` methods instead of `setValue:forKey:` and `valueForKey:`